# low efficiency , update records with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Good day,

I am using entity framework to update a field in my database. The object I want to update, has another object inside it, in this case there will be a relationship of one to many.

```
 public class Rental
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public string SomeValue{get;set;}

    public DateTime DateRented { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }
}
```

The Movie Entity:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}       
    public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

When I am updating the Rental table

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
var result = db.rental.SingleOrDefault(r => id == ID);
if (result != null)
{
    result.SomeValue = "Some new value";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

I receive an error stating that Movie and Customer is required. I could see that the result does not include Movie object , neither Customer object(both come as null).
Is there any way that may help me to update Rental, without having to use Include like this?

```
var result = db.rental.Include(i=>i.Movie)
.Include(i=>i.Customer).SingleOrDefault(r => id == ID);
```

Or making two more queries to bring the Customer and Movie and assign them like

```
result.Customer=Customer;`result.Movie=movie;`
```

Comment: why not remove the required attribute from movie and customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled to false on your context object.

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{

    var result = db.rental.SingleOrDefault(r => id == ID);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.SomeValue = "Some new value";

        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; // <-- set flag to false
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```